# How to create dynamically objects (textFields from native library), and add event to them

Tags: android, ios, lua, coronasdk

I've dynamically created textField using corona, but I can't add events to these objects, because I need to store the information of the textField in a table.

I used to do this in c# by using just one event and I asked for the focus of the textBox, but in this case I don't know what to do. The property focus for the textField doesn't exist (you can set the focus, but you can't ask for the state).

On other hand, I tried to create a table with functions, and pass these functions to `addEventListener` of the textField, but it does't work.

I would appreciate any advice to solve this problem, thanks!!!!

```
local widget=require("widget")
local native=require("native")
local listTextFields={}

local positionY=display.contentCenterY

--Handle for any textField

local function textFieldHandle( event )

if ( event.phase == "began" ) then


elseif ( event.phase == "ended" or event.phase == "submitted" ) then

    --???

elseif ( event.phase == "editing" ) then

    --???
end

end

--this is the button's event
local function buttonEvent_1 (event)

listTextFields[#listTextField+1]=native.newTextField{
x=display.contentCenterX,
y=positionY,
width=100,
height=50
} 
positionY=positionY+70

--This is the main problem


lisTextFields[#listTextFields]:addEventListener("userInput",textFieldHandle)

--But in this case I don't now how to build the handle for the textField,  cause I don't now what textField have the focus.
end


-- Button
local propertiesButton = 
{
left = display.contentCenterX,
top = display.contentCenterY - display.contentHeight/2,
width = 80,
height = 80 ,
label= "Add",
defaultFile = "defaultButton.png",
overFile = "overButton.png",
onPress=buttonEvent_1

}
button1 = widget.newButton(propertiesButton)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The property focus for the textField doesn't exist (you can set the
>   focus, but you can't ask for the state).

Sure you can.
There is a way to know which textField has the focus ..
First let me add a display.newText() for testing .. so at the top before your eventHandlers

```
local test = display.newText( " ", 100, 100, nil, 20 )
```

now add an id property for each of the textFields, so after the creation of the textField we add ..

```
listTextFields[#listTextField+1]=native.newTextField{
x=display.contentCenterX,
y=positionY,
width=100,
height=50
} 

listTextFields[#listTextFields].id = #listTextFields
```

to determine which textField has the focus .. we can use the event.phase == "began" inside the eventHandler .. we can access the textField by event.target ... so now I will display the id of the textField with the focus ..

```
local function textFieldHandle( event )
if ( event.phase == "began" ) then
test.text = "The Focus on the textField # " .. event.target.id
end
end
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: I know, i was hoping i could help by getting more info, then i can update my answer or delete it otherwise, as you mentioned i didnt have enough reputation to comment ..

Comment: I really appreciate your help Muganza, it help me a lot. Thanks